# An harmonic radial function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm taking multivariable-calculus, and I got the following question:

A function $f$ in n variables is called harmonic if $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x_{i}^2}} = 0$. Is there a non-constant, radial harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I found an almost-identical question [here (PDF file)](http://www.bprim.org/Dpset.pdf) (number three), and I'm guessing that the answer is no.

One explanation I could think of, is that if there was such function, it would contradict the [mean value property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property) at the origin. However, we didn't learn about the mean value property (or about harmonic functions in general), so I'm not sure if I'm correct and either way I can't use it. I feel like there is something very simple I'm missing. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: If you change your equation to polar coordinates you'll see that there are radial solutions. Those are considered elementary solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $u$ is a radial harmonic function on the unit ball of $\mathbb R^2$, we can write $u(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$, where $g\colon\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\to\mathbb R$. We have $\partial_x u(x,y)=2xg'(x^2+y^2)$ and $\partial_{xx}u(x,y)=4x^2g''(x^2+y^2)+2g'(x^2+y^2)$ so 
$$\Delta u(x,y)=4(x^2+y^2)g''(x^2+y^2)+4g'(x^2+y^2).$$
We denote $h:=g'$, then for $r>0$ we have $rh'(r)+h(r)=0$, so $(rh(r))'=0$ and $rh(r)$ is constant. If we want $h$ non identically $0$ in order to have $g$ non constant, we have to take $h(r)=Cr^{-1}$ for $C\neq 0$, and $r\in\mathbb R_{>0}$. But $h$ cannot be defined at $0$, and so $g$ cannot be defined at $0$, so necessary $h$ is identically vanishing, $g$ is constant and $u$ is constant.